# issue a new access token (JWT) using an existing access token (JWT) in Fusionauth returns 401 despite authorization JWT cookie

Tags: fusionauth

I follow documentation here: https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/jwt

And try to get issued new JWT to gain access to second application in same tenant. I use [httpie](https://httpie.org/) instead of curl to get access token:

```
source config.sh
ACCESS_TOKEN=`http POST "${URL}/api/login" \
 "Authorization:${API_KEY}" \
 "X-FusionAuth-TenantId:${TENANT1_ID}" \
 "applicationId=${APP1_ID}" \
 "loginId=${USER}" \
 "password=${PASS}" \
 | python -m json.tool | grep token | cut -f4 -d'"'`

echo ${ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

and then I use this access token in following request to get access to second application:

```
source config.sh
JWT=`bash access_token.sh`

http GET ${URL}/api/jwt/issue \
    "Authorization: JWT ${JWT}" \
    "Cookie: access_token=${JWT}" \
    "applicationId=${APP2_ID}"

#http GET ${URL}/api/user \
#        "Authorization: JWT ${JWT}"
```

Notice that commented request to /api/user works well, however request to /api/jwt/issue returns 401.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `applicationId` must come through on a request parameter.
https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/jwt

When using `httpie`, a single equals sign `=` indicates the parameter is to be serialized as JSON in the request body, and a double equals `==` indicates the parameter is to be append to the request URI.

`httpie` help text:

> '==' URL parameters to be appended to the request URI:
>
> ```
> search==httpie
> ```
>
> '=' Data fields to be serialized into a JSON object (with --json, -j)
>       or form data (with --form, -f):
>
> ```
>  name=HTTPie  language=Python  description='CLI HTTP client'
> ```

Try modifying your request to use a double equals `==` for the `applicationId` parameter.

```
http GET ${URL}/api/jwt/issue \
    "Authorization: JWT ${JWT}" \
    "applicationId==${APP2_ID}"
```

Also, you need only to send the cookie or the `Authorization` header. If you send both the `Authorization` header will take precedence. 
https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/authentication#jwt-authentication